# Sharing data with unauthenticated users using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

This is a new area for me and don't know how to achieve this. I am developing a web app using Node.js in which I have some data stored into a database (PostgreSQL). I have a user who has created an account to access that data. Now, this user wants some way (eg. an URL which can be visited) to share that data with others without giving his credentials. How do I do this? After searching on Google for some ideas, I came across to something like RESTful API but have no idea if that is the way to go with or I need to do something else. Please, any suggestions on how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated and what are the best practices to do so. Thanks.

Comment: you would have to generate an auth token and include it as part of the url so that when the person it is shared with visits it, they'll be authenticated by said token. Similar to the kind of temporary token you get when you reset a password, only it would need to not log you in as the logged in user, but instead as an anonymous user with access to only said data.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply @Kevin B. Is it necessary to generate auth token for this? Because user wants to share the data with multiple people. And if I do need to generate token how could I do that? I mean could you please elaborate that and if possible point me to some tutorial or anything that might be helpful?

Comment: i mean.. it's either create an auth token of some sort or just make the data available to everyone always.